# Does DynamoDB allow clients to listen for changes?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to build a real time ordering system where users can see what other people have also ordered in near real time. Will DynamoDB with streams allow me to do this?

```
As a customer
Given there are multiple people ordering
When another customer submits an order
Then I should see that order appear on my screen in near real time
```

Therefore, I need some way for each front end client to subscribe to changes, ideally without having to poll for changes every second.

As far as I can tell, streams allows me to trigger an action such as running a Lambda function on any udpate event but will it allow me to emit changes to any client / user that is listening for changes as well?

Some alternative options I have already tried is web sockets and GCP Firebase. Both work for my use case but I want to know if there is a way to acheive this within DynamoDB.

Comment: Technically every front end client can directly subscribe using the DDB streams client. However it directly ties DDB to the front end, both from coupling and load perspective. Depending on your actual use case, it might not be a good idea.

Comment: You could [connect DynamoDB Streams to SNS](https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-sns/) to fan out the updates. Clients (or a proxy to the clients) could subscribe to the SNS topic.

Comment: @jingx does Firebase have the same issue then? The client application is tightly coupled to the DDB?

Comment: @jarmod that could be a good solution. Do you know if that's how AWS Amplify does it behind the scenes?

Comment: Believe that Amplify uses AppSync and WebSockets under the covers. Also see [Getting Started with Push Notifications using AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/getting-started-with-push-notifications-using-aws-amplify/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best thing to do here is set up a pub/sub system. There are various ways to achieve this:

`DDB -> Streams -> Lambda -> SNS -> Listener`

Or via websocket API

`DDB -> Streams -> Lambda -> APIGW WebSocket -> Listener`

And you can also use Amplify/AppSync PubSub model that allows you to subscribe when you use GraphQL APIs to interact with DynamoDB.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/aws-appsync-real-time-data.html

Comment: This sounds like a really good solution. However, looks like the Stream has to be a Kinesis stream which I can't see any option for that to trigger an SNS message. Do you know if that can be done directly or would I have to go via a Lambda function? i.e. `DDB -> Streams -> Lambda -> SNS -> Listener`

Comment: Streams would need to be consumed via a Lambda function and then pass the payload downstream to either APIGW or SNS.